# Are established network connections to Azure endpoint terminated by firewall or something else?

Tags: networking, azure, connection, endpoint

I have developed an application that resides on a Windows Server 2012 machine in Windows Azure. The application acts as a server for many concurrent network connections, but the traffic is very low and scarce (the clients send information only once every few hours, but they do need to be connected at all times in order to receive updates pushed by the serve).

After several minutes with no traffic, the client/server communication appears to be frozen, with no traffic flowing between the clients and the server. Actually, 30-60 seconds after the clients try to send something they show the connection has been disconnected, and 30-60 seconds later the server acknowledges that as well. If the server is the one trying to send data first, the connection does not time out but the traffic does not flow either.

The same application on my own machine does not freeze at all. I have no other applications installed on the Azure endpoint.

Is it possible to check if Azure is indeed closing the inactive connections? Is it possible to stop this from happening if this is the case? Having keep-alive traffic going on is not possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure is closing IDLE connections after 5 minutes of inactivity.  This limit was 1 minute originally and was increased sometime later.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I believe the load balancer will automatically shut down an inactive connection. Don't really know a way to keep it alive, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create a keep-alive function on your side to basically ping the server side.
Like doing a hello or I am here.